# Canon printer on a Windows share not working

Tags: drivers, networking, printing, sharing, canon

I have a windows 7 machine with a Canon MG5250 connected via USB. It is shared on the network. I have my Ubuntu 11.10 machine on the network also, which I want to print from.

I got as far as browsing the network, finding the printer, adding it, printing to it and Ubuntu reports a successful print. However, the windows print queue spools all the info and reports it as printing even though it doesn't print.

The windows machine prints with no problems.
Very odd. Any clues as to why this might be happening?

screengrabs at
http://up.k10x.net/nbsekxrdwyytq/windialog.jpg 
http://up.k10x.net/uspbajkknkeln/cups.png

thanks in advance, Lozzy

Answer (score 2):

Upon further research, Canon do in fact do their own drivers for both the printer and the scanner of the MG5250, so I decided to give that route a go.

Admittedly, it's not the same route to the printer (i.e via a windows share) but instead directly via wi-fi on the network. Something I opted not to do initially due to poor performance issues under windows.

I got drivers and instructions from
http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010889.asp

Performance seems ok. Both scanner and printer working now.
God bless Canon, if only more manufacturers supported Linux!